# Objective C - searchBarSearchButtonClicked delegate of UIsearchBar not being called after adding shouldChangeTextInRange

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar, uisearchbardelegate

I am trying to implement **UISearchBar** delegate

```
-(BOOL)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)string{

    NSCharacterSet *set = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzQWERTYUIOPLKJHGFDSAZXCVBNM0123456789!@#$%^&*()_+./?'\"\\*- "] invertedSet];

    const char * _char = [string cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    string = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:set] componentsJoinedByString:@""];

    int isBackSpace = strcmp(_char, "\b");

    if((string!=nil && ![string isEqualToString:@""]) || isBackSpace == -8)
    {
        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
```

}

and for search Button clicked

```
-(void) searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBarSender{[mySearchBar resignFirstResponder];
```

}

but **searchBarSearchButtonClicked** delegate is never fired.

I tried removing **shouldChangeTextInRange** then it is being called. What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15089270/searchbarsearchbuttonclicked-doesnt-work-together-with-shouldchangetextinrange)

It was due to i was not passing **\n** character in allowed characters and search uses **\n** to be called.